# Close Mayavi window from ipython

Tags: python, window, ipython, terminate, mayavi

Is there a way to automatically close a Mayavi window after generating an image from an iPython console or notebook?

I usually call `mlab` and then try to close the window with `scene.close()`, but that's not working. For example

```
import mlab
f = mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0))

# ...(do plots)

mlab.show()
f.scene.close()
```

I was thinking in using something like `subprocess` or get the PID of Mayavi, but I cannot figure out how to do that when using `mlab`

Comment: have you tried: 
```mlab.close(all=True)```

Comment: oh.. just realised this was asked 9 months ago...